# Trying to run a program that calculates the needed grade on a final exam to get their desired overall grade

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to run a program that allows a user to input their current overall grade grade (f), their desired overall grade (dg), and the weight of their final exam (g), and would ideally return their needed grade on the final exam to achieve their desired grade.

I have the equation, but am not sure why it is not returning a result on the screen. Can anyone tell me why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>ffdfsdfdsfdsf</title>
<head>
  <script>
       function blahBlah
() {
var f = document.getElementById ('f').value
var f = document.getElementById ('f').value
var f = document.getElementById ('f').value
var f = (f - f *(4 - f)) / f

}
</script>
</head>
<h1> 
f</h1>
<body>
<p>fe: <input id="cg" min="1" max="120" 
onchange="blahBlah"</p>
<p>f: <input id="dg" min="3" max="11" 
onchange="cf"</p>
<p>f: <input id="wof" min="3" max="11" 
onchange="f"</p>
<p><button>Submit</button></p>
<h2 id="f"></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Like I said, ideally there are three forms. Once the user completes these inputs, a pop up of their needed grade on the final would pop up under the submit button.

Answer (score 3):

You had some syntax errors which I have corrected in this snippet, namely you needed to make it a string when you were setting `innerHTML` (thought you should probably use `innerText`), your `<input>` tags weren't closed, and you need to invoke your function with `()` in your `onchange` attributes.

```js
function computeGrade() {
  var cg = document.getElementById("cg").value;
  var dg = document.getElementById("dg").value;
  var wof = document.getElementById("wof").value;
  var ng = (dg - cg * (100 % -wof)) / wof;
  document.getElementById("ng").innerHTML = "Needed_grade: " + ng + "%";
}
```

```html
<h1> Class Calculator</h1>
<p>Current grade: <input id="cg" min="1" max="120" 
onchange="computeGrade()"></input></p>
<p>Desired grade: <input id="dg" min="1" max="120" 
onchange="computeGrade()"></input></p>
<p>Final weight: <input id="wof" min="1" max="100" 
onchange="computeGrade()"</input></p>
<p><button>Submit</button></p>
<h2 id="ng"></h2>
```